# How to skip a zero value and find go to the next non sero cell

Tags: excel

I have the table in the enclosed picture (longer actually).

What i would like to accomplish is: if in column "C" it finds a zero value to skip that row and go to the next row where the coresponding "C"column is not zero and display all the 4 columns. I have to mention that the original table has about 500 rows and i need to print this. Since the data in this table is variable, menaning that it changes as i insert the number of products, it will never be the same. So for different values inserted i may have 200 rows with non zero value or 400 rows with non zero value. Since i have to print this i would like to reduce the number of rows as much as possible, and it can be done only by eliminating the zero values rows.
i have serched online but can't seem to find the right resolution.
Could someone give me a direction or help me?

Comment: There is no image.

Comment: Also just use a filter surely? If needs be you can copy visible cells only to a new sheet for printing.

Comment: i cant find where to attach the image. but the table is consisting in

Comment: i cant find where to attach the image. but the table is consisting in: In column A, values that will never be zero. In column B values that can be zero or not based on my selection of products, in column C the material of which the product is done. Since the resulted table will always be different based on the number of products that i choose it is very time consuming to copy/paste the non zero values to a different sheet and print. And this table for this product has only 500 rows, other 30-40 products may have more than 500 rows. This is why i would like to do this sorting automatically

Answer (score 0):

Apply a filter to your table: click on Sort&Filter, then on Filter and a little dropdown symbol appears in each field in the table header. If you click on that symbol in column C a dropdown menu opens showing all values that exist in that column. You can untick number 0, which hides all rows in the table containing a zero in column C. (It does not delete them, just hides them from view.)

If you want to save the filter result copy the whole sheet while the filter is applied and insert it into a new file.

Comment: Thank you for reply. Your solution does work somehow. The main issue is that whoever is going to use this spreadsheet (not me) doesn't have that much knowledge of excel and will do a lot of errors, since u have to re-filter each time the table by tick-ing and un-ticking all the values in the filter selection. Ive tried your solution, and it works only the first time u aply the filter. i will keep trying to find the solution for my problem

Comment: if you add values to the file, of course you have to apply the filter again. What exactly do you want? A spreadsheet that automatically filters rows every time something is changed or added?

Comment: Yes, exactly. The main ideea of the spreadsheet is: i have many number of types of furnitures (cabinets, tables, beds, sofas...). Each furniture has different components with their coresponding pieces. If i enter 2 as the number for the cabinet and 5 as the numer of sofas, it need to show me all the components only for the cabinets and sofas. If i choose to add another 4 pieces of beds, need to show me also the components for the beds. i mention that i have already reduced the table to 3 columns (product, number of pieces per product and material).

Comment: i found a solution for my problem. Using a macro that hides all the rows with zero value. This macro is updated only when whoever is using it is trying to print the file.